How Can I Visualize KQL Query Results from Azure Log Analytics on a Dashboard via Azure Bicep?
I am exploring options to create a dashboard tile for visualizing data ingestion metrics from an Azure Log Analytics workspace. The challenge is to use Azure Bicep for defining and deploying both the dashboard and the specific tile that should display the results of a KQL query.
Here's the KQL query I need to visualize:
let TopTables = materialize(
    Usage
    | where TimeGenerated > startofday(ago(31d))
    | where StartTime > startofday(ago(31d))
    | where IsBillable
    | summarize IngestedGB=sum(Quantity) / 1.0E3 by DataType
    | sort by IngestedGB desc
    | take 10
    | project DataType);
Usage
| where TimeGenerated > startofday(ago(31d))
| where StartTime > startofday(ago(31d))
| where IsBillable
| extend Table = iff(DataType in (TopTables), DataType, "Other")
| extend Rank = iff(Table == "Other", 2, 1)
| summarize IngestedGB=sum(Quantity) / 1.0E3 by Table, bin(StartTime, 1d), Rank
| sort by Rank asc, IngestedGB desc
| project-away Rank
| project StartTime, IngestedGB
| render columnchart

Dashboard configuration snippet from main.bicep file:
module blobOperationsTransactionCount 'Modules/StorageAccounts/blobTransactionCountTile.bicep' = {
  name: 'blob-transaction-count-tile-${deploymentId}'
  params: {
    deploymentId: deploymentId
    storageAccountsConfig: storageAccountsConfig
  }
}

module queueTransactionCount 'Modules/StorageAccounts/queueTransactionCountTile.bicep' = {
  name: 'queue-transaction-count-tile-${deploymentId}'
  params: {
    deploymentId: deploymentId
    storageAccountsConfig: storageAccountsConfig
  }
}

module queueMessagesCount 'Modules/StorageAccounts/queueMessagesCountTile.bicep' = {
  name: 'queue-messages-count-tile-${deploymentId}'
  params: {
    deploymentId: deploymentId
    storageAccountsWithQueuesConfig: storageAccountsWithQueuesConfig
  }
}

module appServicePlansAverageMemoryUsage 'Modules/AppService/appServicePlanAverageMemoryTile.bicep' = {
  name: 'appservice-plan-memory-usage-tile-${deploymentId}'
  params: {
    deploymentId: deploymentId
    appServicePlansConfig: appServicePlansConfig
  }
}

module appServicePlansAverageCpuUsage 'Modules/AppService/appServicePlanAverageCpuTile.bicep' = {
  name: 'appservice-plan-cpu-usage-tile-${deploymentId}'
  params: {
    deploymentId: deploymentId
    appServicePlansConfig: appServicePlansConfig
  }
}

module appServiceMaxResponseTime 'Modules/AppService/maxResponseTimeTile.bicep' = {
  name: 'appservice-max-response-time-tile-${deploymentId}'
  params: {
    deploymentId: deploymentId
    apiSitesConfig: apiSitesConfig
  }
}

module xxxApiAuthenticationErrors 'Modules/AppService/xxxApiAuthenticationErrorsTile.bicep' = {
  name: 'xxx-api-authentication-errors-tile-${deploymentId}'
  params: {
    deploymentId: deploymentId
    xxxApiSiteConfig: xxxApiSiteConfig
  }
}

module databaseMaxDTUConsumption 'Modules/databaseMaxDTUTile.bicep' = {
  name: 'database-max-dtu-tile-${deploymentId}'
  params: {
    deploymentId: deploymentId
    databasesConfig: databasesConfig
  }
}

module tempStorageAccountErrors './Modules/StorageAccounts/tempStorageAccountErrorsTile.bicep' = {
  name: 'temp-storage-account-errors-tile-${deploymentId}'
  params: {
    deploymentId: deploymentId
    tempStorageAccountConfig: tempStorageAccountConfig
  }
}

resource dashboard 'Microsoft.Portal/dashboards@2020-09-01-preview' = {
  name: 'dashboard-${environmentId}'
  location: location
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    lenses: [
      {
        order: 0
        parts: [
          {
            metadata: blobOperationsTransactionCount.outputs.blobTransactionCountTile
            position: {
              metadata: {}
              colSpan: tileDefaultColSpan
              rowSpan: tileDefaultRowSpan
              x: 0
              y: 0
            }
          }
          {
            metadata: queueTransactionCount.outputs.queueTransactionCountTile
            position: {
              metadata: {}
              colSpan: tileDefaultColSpan
              rowSpan: tileDefaultRowSpan
              x: 0
              y: tileDefaultRowSpan
            }
          }
          {
            metadata: queueMessagesCount.outputs.queueMessagesCountTile
            position: {
              metadata: {}
              colSpan: tileDefaultColSpan
              rowSpan: tileDefaultRowSpan
              x: 0
              y: tileDefaultRowSpan * 2
            }
          }
          {
            metadata: appServicePlansAverageMemoryUsage.outputs.appServicePlansAverageMemoryUsageTile
            position: {
              metadata: {}
              colSpan: tileDefaultColSpan
              rowSpan: tileDefaultRowSpan
              x: tileDefaultColSpan
              y: 0
            }
          }
          {
            metadata: appServicePlansAverageCpuUsage.outputs.appServicePlansAverageCpuUsageTile
            position: {
              metadata: {}
              colSpan: tileDefaultColSpan
              rowSpan: tileDefaultRowSpan
              x: tileDefaultColSpan
              y: tileDefaultRowSpan
            }
          }
          {
            metadata: tempStorageAccountErrors.outputs.tempStorageAccountErrorsTile
            position: {
              metadata: {}
              colSpan: tileDefaultColSpan
              rowSpan: tileDefaultRowSpan
              x: tileDefaultColSpan
              y: tileDefaultRowSpan * 2
            }
          }
          {
            metadata: databaseMaxDTUConsumption.outputs.databaseMaxDTUConsumptionTile
            position: {
              metadata: {}
              colSpan: tileDefaultColSpan
              rowSpan: tileDefaultRowSpan
              x: tileDefaultColSpan * 2
              y: 0
            }
          }
          {
            metadata: appServiceMaxResponseTime.outputs.appServiceMaxResponseTimeTile
            position: {
              metadata: {}
              colSpan: tileDefaultColSpan
              rowSpan: tileDefaultRowSpan
              x: tileDefaultColSpan * 2
              y: tileDefaultRowSpan
            }
          }
          {
            metadata: xxxApiAuthenticationErrors.outputs.xxxApiAuthenticationErrorsTile
            position: {
              metadata: {}
              colSpan: tileDefaultColSpan
              rowSpan: tileDefaultRowSpan
              x: tileDefaultColSpan * 2
              y: tileDefaultRowSpan * 2
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

And each module is referencing template metricsTile.bicep:
param title string
param metrics array

param sort int = 2 // descending - default suggested by the Portal
param top int = 10
param groupingDimension string = ''

param filters object = {}

var metricsValue = [
  for metric in metrics: {
    resourceMetadata: {
      id: metric.resourceId
    }
    namespace: metric.metricNamespace
    name: metric.metricName
    aggregationType: metric.aggregation
    metricVisualization: {
      displayName: metric.displayName
      resourceDisplayName: metric.resourceDisplayName
    }
  }
]

var grouping = {
  dimension: groupingDimension
  sort: sort
  top: top
}

output tile object = {
  type: 'Extension/HubsExtension/PartType/MonitorChartPart'
  inputs: []
  settings: {
    content: {
      options: {
        chart: {
          title: title
          metrics: metricsValue
          grouping: empty(groupingDimension) ? {} : grouping
        }
      }
    }
  }
  filters: filters
}


What specific information do you want to visualize?
